# Filter array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have search-bar that I want to filter my array results but it does not return results.

## Code

`HTML`

```
// search bar
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

// results
<ion-list *ngIf="showList" class="studentsList">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let student of students">
    {{student.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

`Component`

```
students: any[] = []; // sample data array provided below
showList: boolean = false;
searchQuery: string = '';

getItems(event) {
  if (event != '') {
    this.students = this.students.filter((v) => {
      return (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.srcElement.value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    this.showList = true;
  } else {
    this.showList = false;
  }
  console.log('count: ', event.srcElement.value, this.students.length);
}
```

`Sample data array`

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Arina",
            "username": "arina",
            "email": "student1@student.com",
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Tom",
            "username": "tom",
            "email": "tom@student.com",
        }
    ],
    "message": "Students are ready."
}
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

requested data screenshot

[image: one]

Comment: What is the value of "event.srcElement.value" or the console.log output?

Comment: @kvetis is the input user types in search-bar `i.e. tom`

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have `if (event != '')` in one place and `event.srcElement.value` in another. Also, `event` will never be `''` or any `string` and thus `showlist` will always be `true`

Comment: can you please show the console output of this line: `console.log('count: ', event.srcElement.value, this.students.length)` ?

Comment: @Argee sure....

Comment: @AluanHaddad please share what make sense to you it might help solving this issue

Comment: Well, it seems you must be trying to determine if the input was an empty string. But you are treating it as a different type in other places... that can't be right since you don't reassign it. I would do `const value = event.target.value; if (value) {}`. Use value everywhere else as well instead of `event.srcElement.value`

Comment: That fixed the issue? Excellent

Comment: yes it did :). share an answer if you don't mind so i can accept it

Comment: Each call to getItems you replace `this.students` with a filtered array. You then take that filtered array to filter even more. If the filter found no matches the first time. The second time there will be nothing to be filtered. So the list will remain empty. 

My advice is to keep the original data in another variable and do `this.students = this.originalData.filter( ....`.

Comment: @mafortis great. Answer added with a few more suggestions that simply the code and improve performance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues in your method

```
getItems(event) {
  if (event != '') {
    this.students = this.students.filter((v) => {
      return (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.srcElement.value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    this.showList = true;
  } else {
    this.showList = false;
  }
  console.log('count: ', event.srcElement.value, this.students.length);
}
```

Firstly, `event` is not a string based on what you have passed from your Angular markup, `$event`, so `if (event != '')` will always be `true`.

So we actually want to compare the value of the event, with `''` to make sure there is text entered.

We can solve both issues with a minor refactoring as follows

```
getItems(event: Event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value !== '') {
    this.students = this.students.filter((v) => {
      return (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    this.showList = true;
  } else {
    this.showList = false;
  }
  console.log('count: ', value, this.students.length);
}
```

As [Micheal D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6513921/michael-d) astutely observes, if we assign the filtered `students` to `students` property, we will lose the ability to reset any filtering because we won't have the original array.

To resolve this, we need to store the original students in a dedicated property so we can reset our filtered collection back to it. In fact, we should do this when the filter value is emtpty

```
// original students array.
students: Student[] = [];

// filtered array we iterate over in search results
matchingStudents = [];

getItems(event: Event) {
  const value = event.target.value;
  if (value !== '') {
    this.matchingStudents = this.students.filter((v) => {
      return (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    this.showList = true;
  } else {
    this.showList = false;
  }
  console.log('count: ', value, this.matchingStudents.length);
}
```

Finally, I'll do some additional cleanup since your filter can be simplified making it simultaneously more readable and concise

```
getItems(event: Event) {
  const value = (event.target.value || '').toLowerCase();
  this.showList = value !== '';
  if (showList) {
    this.matchingStudents = this.students.filter(v => v.name.toLowerCase().includes(value));
  }
  console.log('count: ', value, this.students.length);
}
```

Template

```
// search bar
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>

// results
<ion-list *ngIf="showList" class="studentsList">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let student of matchingStudents">
    {{student.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: thank you so much, is there any chance to implement `Michael D` idea into this as well?

Comment: Yeah, he catches an important issue.

Comment: also the bug i mentioned in his answer i catch it in your solution as well

Comment: `const value = event.target.value;
    if (value) {
      this.studentsFiltered = this.students.filter((v) => {......`

Comment: I think if not use `this.matchingStudents = this.students;` in `else` part is better so `students` will have no effect on `matchingStudents` while it couldn't find results therefore it will not show anything in view

Answer (score 3):

I see multiple issues.

1. You're assigning the filtered students back to the `this.students` variable. So for the next search, the source list isn't available anymore. I'd say you could introduce another variable to hold the filtered students list.
2. You're checking for an empty event field with condition `event != ''` whereas it should actually be `event.srcElement.value != ''`.

Try the following

Controller

```
studentsFiltered = [];

getItems(event) {
  if (event.srcElement.value != '') {
    this.studentsFiltered = this.students.filter((v) => {
      return (v.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(event.srcElement.value.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    });
    this.showList = true;
  } else {
    this.showList = false;
    this.studentsFiltered = [];
  }
  console.log('count: ', event.srcElement.value, this.studentsFiltered.length);
}
```

Template

```html
<ion-list *ngIf="showList" class="studentsList">
  <ion-item *ngFor="let student of studentsFiltered">
    {{student.name}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: thanks, this is good but the problem is no matter what i type i always get some results even if those typed letters are not include any of students names.

Comment: I've combined your both answers and it works like charm :)

Comment: `const value = event.target.value;
    if (value) {
      this.studentsFiltered = this.students.filter((v) => {....`

Comment: I didn't test it. Nice that @AluanHaddad's answer solved the issue :)

Comment: @MichaelD well, you solved a big part of it as well. +1